# Locking the rows after a specific date in google sheets

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking

I am a newbie. I am having problems with creating a locking scripts for my time sheets of employees so I would like to get some advices from you guys. The main purpose is to lock the rows based on coresponding  date information at the same rows. The row will be locked if the date has passed.
You can have a clear view as my google sheets file below: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b0zP1NCgjdRdIjjJJx94mrgqEpEUbU3kE9PjkygsCFI/edit?usp=sharing

I have try many codes in this forum but they are either not working or having errors while running.
I have to get some advices to be able to get a propper codes.Any advices would be really appreciated! Thank you for reading.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result?

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining fully, I'm bad at English too. All I want to do is prevent employees from editing the check-in and check-out times that they are required to fill in on each working day. I mean they can only edit those two columns on that specific day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `All I want to do is prevent employees from editing the check-in and check-out times that they are required to fill in on each working day. I mean they can only edit those two columns on that specific day.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result?